# How to not generate .png.aux.xml files when using gdal2tiles?

Tags: gdal, tiles, gdal2tiles

I am trying to use the GDAL Python script gdal2tiles.py to create a few sets of map tiles. Whenever I execute the script, it also creates a set of .png.aux.xml files for every regular map tile (.png). It does this for most zoom levels, but not all.

My problem is I would like to avoid generating these XML files entirely and I'm not sure how. I'm not sure why they're being created in the first place and I don't recall them being created before. Although I could delete all of them afterward, the datasets are rather large so I'd like to reduce the processing as much as possible.

It is my understanding that these are georeferenced images. I have tried looking online for anything about this issue but couldn't find what I needed. Does this relate to the difference between "Base Tiles" and "Overview Tiles"? Would specifying a EPSG help? Here is the command I used to tile. Perhaps one of my options is causing this to happen:

```
gdal2tiles.py --resampling=near --xyz --zoom=3-13 --srcnodata=0 --exclude --processes=4 --tilesize=256 dataset-raster.tif tile-output
```

Note that this seems to happen whether I'm tiling GeoTIFFs or VRTs. I am using GDAL version 3.3.2 on Linux Mint Xfce.

Comment: I do not really know why aux.xml files are generated but I get those as well with GDAL 3.4.1. I had some older tile directories remaining on my computer and there were no aux.xml files. I suggest to write mail to gdal-dev mailing list and ask. I think there is not any necessary information in the aux.xml files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL uses the .aux.xml files to store metadata, including statistics. You can disable completely by setting the environment variable [`GDAL_PAM_ENABLED=NO`](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ConfigOptions#GDAL_PAM_ENABLED) though I don't advise doing this permanently.

Linux:

```
export GDAL_PAM_ENABLED=NO
gdal2tiles.py --resampling=near --xyz --zoom=3-13 --srcnodata=0 --exclude --processes=4 --tilesize=256 dataset-raster.tif tile-output
```

Windows:

```
set GDAL_PAM_ENABLED=NO
gdal2tiles.py --resampling=near --xyz --zoom=3-13 --srcnodata=0 --exclude --processes=4 --tilesize=256 dataset-raster.tif tile-output
```

If temporarily disabling PAM support causes issues with `gdal2tiles.py`, you can leave it enabled, but tell GDAL to store the .aux.xml files in another directory by setting the environment variable `GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR` to a different folder

Linux:

```
export GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR=/tmp
```

Windows

```
set GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR=%TEMP%
```

Comment: PAM files that gdal2tiles create look pretty useless: `<PAMDataset>
  <GeoTransform>  0.0000000000000000e+00,  1.0000000000000000e+00,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  0.0000000000000000e+00,  1.0000000000000000e+00</GeoTransform>
  <Metadata domain="IMAGE_STRUCTURE">
    <MDI key="INTERLEAVE">PIXEL</MDI>
  </Metadata>
</PAMDataset>` and disabling them should be safe.

Answer (score 1):

Since this commit (2022-05-02) gdal2tiles does not write the .png.aux.xml files any more. Because the change is in the Python script there is no need to wait for the next GDAL release but users can just add the few new lines into existing gdal2tiles.py script.

[gdal2tiles: do not generate .aux.xml files on overview tiles](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/commit/b210a94899e5c10645263604b350347cc13d369f)

Comment: Is this also true for `gdal_retile`?

Comment: Have yor tried?

Comment: Yes and it did produce .aux, ended up using `os.envir['GDAL_PAM_PROXY_DIR']='NO'`. Why would gdal_retile not be updated and gdal2tiles is? Is gdal2tiles meant to replace gdal_retile?

Comment: They are different tools. Gdal2tiles does not replace gdal_retile. I guess nobody has reported that gdal_retile has that behavior.

Comment: It is possible that I am using an older gdal_retile script, but I belive I updated it with the newest one.

Comment: The newest of all is here https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/swig/python/gdal-utils/osgeo_utils/gdal_retile.py. I think it does not have code to prevent creating the aux.xml files. Script in rather complicated and improvement may require more than just copy-paste.